# Implementing a Gaussian filter in Python, Error: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, numpy

I'm not sure what is causing the tuple index out of range error because I'm using for loops not an if statement like some of the earlier posts on here. This is on a Jupyter notebook and I think the latest version of Anaconda/Jupyter. I'm a relative beginner with Python.

Current code:

```
def gaussian_filter(size: int, sigma: float): 
    
    #create a 2d array, index x and y, accounting for image pixels
    #for each x in size, for each y in size, compute gaussian function
    #fill output array
    #return output array
    #max_arr = size
    kernel = np.zeros((size, size))
    new_elem = 0
    print (kernel.shape[0]) #is this a scalar or a vector
    for row in range(kernel.shape[0]):
        for col in range(kernel.shape[1]):
            kernel[row][col]= 1/(2*np.pi*sigma)**2*np.exp(-(kernel[row]- 
    np.mean(kernel[row],axis=1))**2 + (kernel[col]-np.mean(kernel[col], axis=0))**2/ (2* 
   (sigma**2)))
            new_elem = new_elem + kernel(row, col)
            break
        break
    kernel = kernel/new_elem
    return kernel
```

Test code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,4,figsize=(1 + 4*4.5,4))
for i in range(1,5):
   gauss_filt = gaussian_filter(21,i)
   display_axis(ax[i-1],gauss_filt,f'\u03C3={i}', normalized=True)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('Data/Solutions/question_3_2.pdf', format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Error message with traceback calls:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-181-9219628082d0> in <module>
      1 fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,4,figsize=(1 + 4*4.5,4))
      2 for i in range(1,5):
----> 3     gauss_filt = gaussian_filter(21,i)
      4     display_axis(ax[i-1],gauss_filt,f'\u03C3={i}', normalized=True)
      5 fig.tight_layout()

<ipython-input-180-7224d0764ce5> in gaussian_filter(size, sigma)
     14     for row in range(kernel.shape[0]):
     15         for col in range(kernel.shape[1]):
---> 16             kernel[row][col]= 1/(2*np.pi*sigma)**2*np.exp(-(kernel[row]-np.mean(kernel[row], axis=1))**2 + (kernel[col]-np.mean(kernel[col], axis=0))**2/ (2*(sigma**2)))
     17             new_elem = new_elem + kernel(row, col)
     18             break

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
   3116 
   3117     return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
-> 3118                           out=out, **kwargs)
   3119 
   3120 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     60 
     61     is_float16_result = False
---> 62     rcount = _count_reduce_items(arr, axis)
     63     # Make this warning show up first
     64     if rcount == 0:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _count_reduce_items(arr, axis)
     53     items = 1
     54     for ax in axis:
---> 55         items *= arr.shape[ax]
     56     return items
     57 

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening because in the end of this line

```
 kernel[row][col]= 1/(2*np.pi*sigma)**2*np.exp(-(kernel[row]- 
    np.mean(kernel[row],axis=1))**2 + (kernel[col]-np.mean(kernel[col], axis=0))**2/ (2* 
   (sigma**2)))
```

You are just doing `kernel[col]`  which is indexing the row with the amount of columns you have. So there must be more columns than rows. I think you just want to do this:

```
kernel[row][col]
```

Comment: After making the suggested changes, I'm now getting a "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence" error with the same line of code. I don't really understand why.

Comment: You don't want to have two indices in separate calls to `__getitem__` like that pretty much ever.

Comment: @user15087536 when you do `kernel[col]` are you trying to access the entire column.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i see some problems in your code:

When you call `np.mean(kernel[row],axis=1)` i think it will throw an error, because it is a 1d array, so that axis arg wont make sense.
If you want the mean of each row or column, you can create arrays like this:

```
means_row = kernel.mean(axis = 1)
means_col = kernel.mean(axis = 0)
```

and call `means_row[row]` and `means_col[col]` for each iteration

Also you must take care with the `kernel[col]` call. If you really wish the column you should use this:

```
kernel[:,col]
```

otherwise, it will return the row indexed by col, and may throw a error if the the matrix is not square.

Also, when you call `kernel[col]` and `kernel[row]` you are expecting the array, or just one single value?

And do you really want that "break" after the loops? It will break the iterations, so you will really compute just for col and row = 0

Finally, take care of this`kernel(row, col)`. In python you should go like `kernel[row][col]`

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback! I just want to calculate the gaussian for every element inside the 2d array [[col][col]] where row is the size of the larger array etc.

Comment: and what would be the \mu (the center of the distribution) and the \sigma parameters? The \mu would be the mean of the columns?